# Python Tkinter display the array index in label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on display the array index and the `x` value in label.

My code is as below:

```
from Tkinter import *
top = Tk()
top.geometry("450x550+500+5")
top.title("Display Data")
labelframe = LabelFrame(top,text="",width=300, height=350,bd = 2)
labelframe.pack(fill="both")
labelframe.config(relief=RIDGE)

response = 'FF FF FF 00 00 00 10 00 0A 00 C5 00 00'
r = response[9:].replace(' ', '')
x = [ord(c) for c in r.decode('hex')]
# for index,x in enumerate(x,start=0):   

Label(labelframe, text='My first data:').grid(row=1, column=1, sticky = W,pady = 10)

Label(labelframe, text='Data_array_').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky = W)

top.mainloop()
```

I am excepting to display in label as below:

```
Data_array_[0] = 0
Data_array_[1] = 0
Data_array_[2] = 0
Data_array_[3] = 16
Data_array_[4] = 0
Data_array_[5] = 10
Data_array_[6] = 0
Data_array_[7] = 192
Data_array_[8] = 0
Data_array_[9] = 0
```

I am trying:

```
for index,x in enumerate(x,start=0):
```

Not able to get the solution to add in the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do a .split() on response that way you keep the association between the data and the index in the array. Your label's text data is then.

```
'\n'.join(["Data_array_[{}] = {}".format(index, response[index+9].decode('hex')) for index in range(9,len(response[9:].split()))])
```

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable